Creating a 'for' or 'if-else' selector for checking dynamically sized python List
I'm trying to mask 8752 images with transformers like this
from transformers import pipeline
from PIL import Image
import requests
import cv2

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


semantic_segmentation_nvidia = pipeline("image-segmentation", "nvidia/segformer-b0-finetuned-ade-512-512")
jpeg_im = None
a = 0
mask_i = 0

f = open("masking_log.txt", "w")


for im in large_image_stack_512:
    i=0 
    while(i == 0):
        
        jpeg_im = Image.open(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR,im))
        print(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR,im))
        # Semantic segmentation
        segmentation = semantic_segmentation_nvidia(jpeg_im)
        print("the length of current segmentation labels are: ", len(segmentation))
        water_mask_label = segmentation[mask_i]["label"]
        print(water_mask_label)
        print("here")    
        if (water_mask_label == "water"):
            print("Successful labelling at: ", mask_i)
            water_mask = segmentation[mask_i]["mask"]
            print("here")
            imar = np.asarray(water_mask)
            print(water_mask_label)
            print("type im (array)", type(imar))
            f.write("image " + str(a) + "\nsuccess-label at " + str(mask_i) + "\nwith dir: " + str(im)  + "\n with mask labeled as: " + str(water_mask_label) + '\n\n')
            plt.imsave('D:\..\Data\'+'img_'+str(a)+'.jpg', imar, cmap="gray")  
            i=1
            a+=1
            mask_i= 0
            semantic_jpeg = None
            imar = None
            water_mask = None
            water_mask_label = None
            segmentation = None
            water_mask_label = None
        else:       
            print("not water")
            if (mask_i < len(segmentation)):
                mask_i += 1
            else:
                f.write("image " + str(a) + "\n unsuccess-labelling (has no 'water' label)" + "final mask_i value: " + str(mask_i) + "\nwith dir: " + str(im)  + "\n check later " +  + '\n\n')
                print("masking fails, check later image" + im)
                i = 1
                continue
            
            
        #plt.imshow(water_mask)
        #plt.show()
        #print("type jpeg_im (jpeg)", type(water_mask))
    continue   
       
#print(len(cropped))
f.close()

Each of segmentation = semantic_segmentation_nvidia(jpeg_im) will have different size of array, for example with this image I have 11 items inside it like this:
The code (did this in jupyter notebook rows)
a_512 = semantic_segmentation_nvidia(image_512)
a_512

the output, a_512 variable is a List with 11 items inside it
[{'score': None,
  'label': 'wall',
  'mask': <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=512x512>},
 {'score': None,
  'label': 'building',
  'mask': <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=512x512>},
 {'score': None,
  'label': 'sky',
  'mask': <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=512x512>},
 {'score': None,
  'label': 'tree',
  'mask': <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=512x512>},
 {'score': None,
  'label': 'earth',
  'mask': <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=512x512>},
 {'score': None,
  'label': 'water',
  'mask': <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=512x512>},
 {'score': None,
  'label': 'fence',
  'mask': <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=512x512>},
 {'score': None,
  'label': 'railing',
  'mask': <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=512x512>},
 {'score': None,
  'label': 'bridge',
  'mask': <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=512x512>},
 {'score': None,
  'label': 'ship',
  'mask': <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=512x512>},
 {'score': None,
  'label': 'pier',
  'mask': <PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=512x512>}]

To access things I need, probably the 'label', I need to access the PIL.Image.Imagedata from each List item like this
(a_512[5]["mask"]

In the codes above, I used a variable to represent 5 in this code because apparently each image has different order of when it detects 'water' as the label and thus the required mask.
Because python can compare strings, I'm trying to make a for loop to check every items in the list of every 8752 images. Let's say some of the images can have 10-12 items like this output of the final run.
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2541.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  15
car
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2541.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  15
water
here
Successful labelling at:  7
here
water
type im (array) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12
wall
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12
building
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12
sky
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12
tree
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12
road
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12
mountain
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12
car
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12
sea
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12
fence
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12
bridge
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12
boat
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12
ship
here
not water
D:\..\Data\cropped_512\img_2542.jpg
the length of current segmentation labels are:  12

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 17
     15 segmentation = semantic_segmentation_nvidia(jpeg_im)
     16 print("the length of current segmentation labels are: ", len(segmentation))
---> 17 water_mask_label = segmentation[mask_i]["label"]
     18 print(water_mask_label)
     19 print("here")    

IndexError: list index out of range

As you can see the index keeps increasing and didn't touch the last else of the if-else comparator, so it went out of bounds. I have tried this and using range on the for-loop but it didn't work and still went out of bounds. I put breaks and it stops the loop, I put continue it keeps went out of bounds.Which part did I do wrong and understood incorrectly about python comparator behavior?
I also tried logging it into .txt file or give status with print but it didn't go that way and always go out of bounds. Will gladly add more details if needed. The image is 512 x 512 size.

I assume the problem lies at the following point: if (mask_i < len(segmentation)): mask_i += 1. If mask_i is now equal to len(segmentation), then it is out of bounds. You should increment it first, and then check to see that it is not equal to the length.

this cannot be your code. Are you saving in "D:D:\..\Data\"  ??

The directory is changed for privacy reason, is there nothing wrong with the code logic? Oh wait I'll change that sorry

@OldBoy so the mask_i+=1 is beyond the if else then? won't it change the mask or like..take new image from the array? Oh do I need to put the large_image_stack_512 method? it's filled with images address. Wait nvm, let me try that

Sorry, but I cannot tell just from looking at the code. My guess is trhat somewhere in the loops you are not restting the value of mask_i when starting to process some new data. You need to add some more debug statements to your code, or run it in the debugger to identify where the values is being set wrongly.

@OldBoy I fixed it thanks to you, will post the answer soon

The problem is solved according to @OldBoy input to move the increment.
full code
mask_i = 0
a = 0

f = open("masking_log.txt", "w")

for im in large_image_stack_512:
    image_success_flag = 0
    mask_i= 0
    
    while(image_success_flag < 1):
        jpeg_im = Image.open(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR,im))
        print(os.path.join(ROOT_DIR,im))
        # Semantic segmentation
        segmentation = semantic_segmentation_nvidia(jpeg_im)
        print("the length of current segmentation labels are: ", len(segmentation))
        while(mask_i < len(segmentation)):
           image_mask = segmentation[mask_i]["label"]
           print(image_mask)
           if(image_mask == "water"):
               print("correct mask")
               water_mask = segmentation[mask_i]["mask"]
               imar = np.asarray(water_mask)
               plt.imsave('D:/semester_12/Data_Irredeano/'+'img_'+str(a)+'.jpg', imar, cmap="gray") 
               print("here")
               f.write("image " + str(a) + "\nsuccess-label at " + str(mask_i) + "\nwith dir: " + str(im)  + "\n with mask labeled as: " + str(water_mask_label) + '\n\n')
               print("mask-succesfully saved")
               mask_i = 0 
               break
           elif(image_mask != "water"):
               mask_i+=1
               print("number of mask: ", mask_i)
               if(mask_i == len(segmentation)):
                    print("this image has no correct mask, check later")
                    f.write("image " + str(a) + "\n unsuccess-labelling (has no 'water' label) final \n mask_i value: " + str(mask_i) + "\nwith dir: " + str(im)  + "\n check later " + '\n\n')
               image_success_flag=+1  
        a+=1


f.close()

Basically instead of selecting mask by checking the segmentation[mask_i]["label] I check if the 'cursor' or mask_i if it's smaller than the  length of the List (len(segmentation)). The += also contribute to the problem since it's adding first then change the number, as implied here and here, because of that my 'cursor variable' can move beyond the array size before checking the segmentation[mask_i]["label]. But I don't think I have other choice other than that to increment since =+ is just redefining itself.
Other than that I also add another while condition to make sure the code runs while the mask_i is below the size of the List, so the program become "if it's still below the list size, check whether mask is "water" or not "water".
Although the program is finished and can mask most of the images, I still have to log several different images since not all of them had "water" as the label, but something close like "Sea" that we humans can intuitively say they are basically the same but computer that can only compare strings not.
Thank you again for everyone who's willing to help, I'm accepting if there's better way to do it
